# Execute qml->build execute file from Another qml gui

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qprocess

I'm trying to figure out, how to execute qml build run file from another qml gui button, when onclicked event happened, it should execute another qml build exe file, I have tried with QProcess, but I'm unable to figure out QProcessEnvironment for qml build.

```
QString filepath="/QML TYPES/build-Task-Desktop_Qt_5_15_0_GCC_64bit-Debug/Task";
QProcess process;
QProcessEnvironment env = QProcessEnvironment::systemEnvironment();
env.insert("TMPDIR", "/home/ubuntu/Qt/5.15.0/gcc_64/bin/qml"); // Add an environment variable
env.insert("COMPILER", env.value("Compiler") + "/usr/lib/ccache/x86_64-linux-gnu-g++");
process.setProcessEnvironment(env);
process.start(filepath);
```

But, Unfortunately above code is not working, so, please help to get out of this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what does your  "not working" mean? Do you get some error/warning/whatever? What is `filepath`? Please clarify the question

Comment: Thanks for your replay, Ill clarify it here filepath is path of qml build run file, When user clicks on a button, onClicked, it should execute a qml project throught build file, i.ee.., example in terminal (linux), we can execute qml project just buy using "./project_name" file, same way when user clicks that button in background qml rproject build exe file should get executed.

Comment: Are you sure the necessary QT environment variables are present? Btw, what are you trying to achieve in the bigger picture? If you want to reload your program itself (say, during development cycle), there are other ways

Comment: I want to run build file of one qml project from another qml. Example  consider chrome as one qml project, if you open amazon in chrome it navigates to amazon application if application is installed in your mobile  here consider amazon also one qml project build file, in the same way, I want to run a build file of qml project from another qml, running one qml project  from another qml project.

Comment: Check twice the path. What /QML is? Are you sure you have such folder?

Comment: Yes, the path is correct but, I don't that  environment is correct or not , example I want to run python file from qt, I use QProcess process; process.start("python3",filename);,in the way here python3 compiles python file, in the same way which thing compiles qml build file, actually in terminal we use "./", to execute run file.